# Android SQLite "random" rows seem inaccessible

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, delete-row

I have a database with 4 columns. Everything works fine except for the fact that random rows remain inaccessible. I cannot seem to update or delete them. I've used the right code:

**DELETION CODE:**

```
boolean deleted=db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_BLAH + "=" + alarm, null) > 0;
```

**CODE FOR UPDATE:**

```
db.update(TABLE_NAME, args, KEY_BLAH + "=" + blah, null)
```

The deletion code returns `false` and the update code returns `0` for some rows, which are arbitrary. The rows are implemented into a `ListView`. Any changes on the `ListView` elements should be reflected in the `SQLite Database`. Most of the times the code works. It doesn't seem to work for random rows at random points though. I do not think this is SDK related. I've tried it on `ICS`, `GB` and `JB`.

I've also tried `deleting` the row and `inserting` it. Obviously this wouldn't work because my `delete` statement doesn't seem to work. The logic for this was, if the `update` wasn't possible it would `delete` the row and `insert` the row with the same row id and different data. So, the `deleted` variable was the condition for an `if-block` which didn't get executed.

**EDIT**

Example:

`1 1414 000 off`

When I click on a few buttons in the list item.

It should become

`1 1414 064 off`

Now, this works most of the times except for some random rows as I said before.

Comment: Please show an example of the values in a row, and the `alarm` value that you think should match.

Comment: And what is the `blah` column? And what is the `blah` value you're trying to match?

Comment: `blah` is the second column. `1414`. It varies with row, obviously.

Comment: And how do you write that value into the table?

Comment: When it's first written onto the DB, using the insert function.

Comment: Is it a number or a string?

Comment: It's a string. Does it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you (indirectly) execute an SQL statement like this:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET x = '064' WHERE blah = 1414
```

then the values in the `blah` column are compared with the *number* 1414.

When using strings in SQL statements, you should always use parameters to avoid formatting problems like this (and [SQL injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/)):

```java
db.update(TABLE_NAME, args, KEY_BLAH + "= ?", new String[] { blah })
```